# Inserting prefix before output of lines printed by awk command

Tags: bash, awk

My program prints the even lines of every file in the current directory:

```
for file in . *
do
  awk 'NR % 2 == 0' "$file"
done
```

I would like it to print the name of the file followed by a colon before every line in the output. I can't find a way to insert anything while the awk command is doing it's job. Is it impossible to do this using awk? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` supports the [`FILENAME`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03) variable which contains, guess what?, the filename. You don't even need the shell loop. Simply:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0 {printf "%s:%s\n", FILENAME, $0}' *
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
IFS=$'\r\n'
for file in . *
do
    for line in `awk 'NR % 2 == 0' "$file"`
    do
        echo $file: $line
    done
done
```